# Using Oracle MERGE on same table based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, upsert, sql-merge

I have created an Oracle sequence as below:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TASK_ID_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE NOCYCLE;
```

I have a database table `TASK` as below:

```
TASK_ID nextval from TASK_ID_SEQ
TASK_DATE   SYSDATE
TASK_TYPE   <value fed from data>
```

I need to insert a fresh `TASK` record if the `TASK_TYPE` does not already appear in the `TASK` table for the date in `TASK_DATE`, otherwise ignore it.

Is the following syntax correct?

```
MERGE INTO TASK a
USING (SELECT b.task_date FROM TASK b) 
ON (a.task_type = b.task_type)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
[INSERT INTO TASK]
```

Or should it be as:

```
MERGE INTO TASK a
USING (SELECT b.task_date FROM TASK b) 
ON (a.task_type = b.task_type)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
[]
WHEN MATCHED THEN
[INSERT INTO TASK]
```

Can I alternately use

```
MERGE INTO TASK USING (select 1 from DUAL) . . .
```

Please do suggest.

Comment: If it is only an insert then why not use an insert statement using select?

Comment: @user75ponic two reasons, one to accommodate update in future with minimal changes and secondly do you anticipate that Merge will be slower than insert? If not,then why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your business rule indicates a match on DATE and TYPE. So there are two things wrong with your code:

1. the USING clause needs to select all the criteria necessary for determining a match.
2. the ON clause needs to test all the criteria necessary for determining a match.

Also, if you don't need to update existing records you can omit the WHEN MATCHED branch. So your MERGE statement should look something like this:

```
merge into task 
using ( 
    select date '2017-05-08' as dt, 'BATTLE' as typ from dual union all
    select date '2017-05-08' as dt, 'JUGGLE' as typ from dual union all
    select date '2017-05-08' as dt, 'PLOT' as typ from dual ) q
on (task.task_date = q.dt
    and task.task_type = q.typ)
when not matched then 
    insert values (task_id_seq.nextval, q.dt, q.typ)
/
```

A demo. Given this starting point ...

```
SQL> select * from task;

   TASK_ID TASK_DATE  TASK_TYPE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 2017-05-06 CLEAN
         2 2017-05-06 BATTLE
         3 2017-05-06 JUGGLE
         4 2017-05-07 JUGGLE
         5 2017-05-07 CLEAN
         6 2017-05-07 NAP
         7 2017-05-08 BATTLE

7 rows selected.
SQL>
```

... the above MERGE should insert two rows (one row in the data source matches an existing row).

```
SQL> merge into task 
  2  using ( 
  3     select date '2017-05-08' as dt, 'BATTLE' as typ from dual union all
  4     select date '2017-05-08' as dt, 'JUGGLE' as typ from dual union all
  5     select date '2017-05-08' as dt, 'PLOT' as typ from dual ) q
  6  on (task.task_date = q.dt
  7     and task.task_type = q.typ)
  8  when not matched then 
  9     insert values (task_id_seq.nextval, q.dt, q.typ)
 10  /  

2 rows merged.

SQL> select * from task
  2  /

   TASK_ID TASK_DATE  TASK_TYPE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 2017-05-06 CLEAN
         2 2017-05-06 BATTLE
         3 2017-05-06 JUGGLE
         4 2017-05-07 JUGGLE
         5 2017-05-07 CLEAN
         6 2017-05-07 NAP
         7 2017-05-08 BATTLE
         9 2017-05-08 JUGGLE
        10 2017-05-08 PLOT

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

The data source is not entirely clear. So in the above example I generated a set of tasks using DUAL. If what you want is to create a new set of tasks for today from the set for yesterday the USING clause would look like this:

```
merge into task 
using ( 
    select trunc(sysdate) as dt, task_type as typ 
    from task
    where task_date = trunc(sysdate) - 1 ) q
on (task.task_date = q.dt
    and task.task_type = q.typ)
when not matched then 
    insert values (task_id_seq.nextval, q.dt, q.typ)
/
```

Using the same starting data as before this version inserts three rows:

```
SQL> select * from task;

   TASK_ID TASK_DATE  TASK_TYPE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 2017-05-06 CLEAN
         2 2017-05-06 BATTLE
         3 2017-05-06 JUGGLE
         4 2017-05-07 JUGGLE
         5 2017-05-07 CLEAN
         6 2017-05-07 NAP
         7 2017-05-08 BATTLE
        11 2017-05-08 CLEAN
        12 2017-05-08 JUGGLE
        13 2017-05-08 NAP

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```